# Google speech to text api latency issue

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

I tried to convert audio file (WAV format) to text using Google speech to text API and have a query on the response time. Below is the code and the response duration.

The audio file is around 30kb and is 3 seconds long. Speech to text service took around 1.7 seconds to transcribe which I believe is too high and should be in milliseconds. Is this normal or am I missing some configuration?

Appreciate any suggestions.

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const fs = require('fs');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

// The name of the audio file to transcribe
const fileName = 'xxx.wav';

// Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
const file = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');


// The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
const audio = {
content: audioBytes,
};
const config = {
encoding: 'MULAW',
sampleRateHertz: 8000,
languageCode: 'en-GB',
model: 'default',
use_enhanced: 'true',
metadata: {InteractionType: 'VOICE_SEARCH',
microphoneDistance: 'NEARFIELD',
OriginalMediaType: 'AUDIO',
RecordingDeviceType: 'PHONE_LINE'},
};
const request = {
audio: audio,
config: config,
};

const [response] = await client.recognize(request);

const transcription = response.results
.map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
.join('\n');
console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your network connection speed (internet speed)

if your network speed will be slow , the overall response time will be more.

check the file upload time to the google cloud.